# How to resolve System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize my class. But i got the following exception,

```
  System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There was an error generating the XML document.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o)
       at FormDemo.Form1.PivotGridSettings() in D:\Feature\XML Serialization\CS\Form1.cs:line 75
       at FormDemo.Form1..ctor() in D:\Feature\XML Serialization\CS\Form1.cs:line 32
       at FormDemo.Program.Main() in D:\Feature\XML Serialization\CS\Program.cs:line 25
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.
       Source=System.Xml
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
            at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.CreateUnknownTypeException(Type type)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterCustomSerializer.Write20_Type(String n, String ns, Type o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterCustomSerializer.Write24_CustomClass(String n, String ns, CustomEngine o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterCustomSerializer.Write25_CustomClass(String n, String ns, CustomSeriaizer o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterCustomSerializer.Write26_CustomSerializer(Object o)
       InnerException:
```

My Serialization code is

```
XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter("CustomClassSchema.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSerializer));
CustomSerializer customSerializer = new CustomSerializer()
serializer.Serialize(xw, customSerializer);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Is there any customization that i need to do with my custom class or any?

Comment: We need to see your `CustomSerializer` class definition. In essence, some part of that class is not serializable. Also, it seems like you're trying to... serialize a serializer? That seems a bit bizarre, to say the least.

Comment: Thanks..But my custom class is large code part. Can you please point out me what are all the possible root causes for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not able to provide a definition for your `CustomSerializer` class (judging by the name it's a strange thing to try and serialize...), then the reason you are seeing this error is because the class contains a public property which either IS a `RuntimeType` or inherits from `RuntimeType` or contains a `RuntimeType` property itself. Or perhaps your entire class inherits `RuntimeType`?

In any case, it seems `RuntimeType` is not serializable, thus you are getting the exception you see.

Again, not knowing what your `CustomSerializer` is I cannot point to the exact solution - it might be as simple as making a property not serializable...

Comment: thanks. I had declared property as Type. Now i resolved it by including the [XmlIgnore] attribute